# Flash in Lazarus OsX

Tags: macos, flash, browser, lazarus

I want to embed Flash into Lazarus under Mac Os. 
I have read that people had some success under Windows and Linux while using Mozilla Plugin Panel but that doesn't work on OS X (plus, that project is dead ) Has anyone had some success doing this? Do you have any other ideas on how to embed Flash in Lazarus? Or maybe a web browser that can play flash.

Answer (score 0):

[GeckoPort2](http://wiki.freepascal.org/GeckoPort_version2) works with the Carbon widgetset, but as the docs state, you need to pass a native window to initialise the browser component.

If you are using the [Qt widgetset](http://users.telenet.be/Jan.Van.hijfte/qtforfpc/fpcqt4.html), you could try embedding the Qt WebKit browser.